# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Adding the optional Analytics feature has no effect

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have installed the Eclipse Juno SR2 client for Worklight 6.1 EE and when I add the optional analytics feature to the application-descriptor.xml file, I do not see any Tealeaf libraries added to the project.

I am running on Mac v10.9.

Any ideas?

Comment: Adding the comment that I saw him correctly add the optional features myself through screen share and that this is a problem for all of his optional features, not just analytics.

Comment: user3081011, you're using "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" edition of Juno SR2?  This one?  http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2

Answer (score 1):

Using Eclipse Java EE 4.3.1 ("Kepler" SR1) and Worklight 6.1 Developer Edition* on a Mac running OS X 10.9, I have done the following:

1. Created a new Worklight project and application
2. Added the Android, iPad and iPhone environments
3. In the `application-descriptor.xml`'s Design view I chose `Optional Features > Analytics`
4. Re-built the project

Outcome:

- For iPad and iPhone, the existing empty Tealeaf folder under `native\Tealeaf` now got populated with library and bundle files
- For Android, the `native\libs` folder got populated with `uicandroid.jar`

Similarly, for JSONStore and FIPS 140-2, files were added to the projects upon build.

---

Make sure these are the steps you've been following.
If you have any related errors in the `Errors` view in Eclipse while adding the optional features, do mention this.

*There is no (technical) difference between the various Worklight editions other than the exclusion of App Authenticity from the Developer Edition.

Comment: Yes, I did the exact same thing as you and got the exact same result as you did. I then instructed him to do the same thing I did and watched him do it in screen share. Theres something different about his configuration that is causing it not to work. I'm not sure if its a local configuration issue or a really obscure defect.

Comment: The user can try in another machine and if it works there, then do a diff on the machines. :-)